# Python scatter plot: soft clustering

Tags: python, matplotlib, cluster-analysis, scatter-plot

I have 2D data that I clustered using EM algorithm with soft classification. There are 3 different clusters, therefore I have a probability vector with dimension (n_clusters, n_datapoints).

Now I'd like to plot the individual datapoints in a scatter plot and assign a certain color to each cluster. The color of each point is given according to the probability to be in each cluster and thus a mixture of the cluster colors.

All I could achieve by now is the following with red, green and blue cluster colors

[Scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOS4e.png)

by using the following lines of code:

```
for n in range(X.shape[0]):
    color = np.array([P[0,n],P[1,n],P[2,n]])[np.newaxis]
    plt.scatter(X[n,0],X[n,1],c=color)
```

How can I assign a different, specific color to each cluster? E.g. orange for class 0, blue for class 1, magenta for class 2.

Comment: Please notice that the correct tag here is `cluster-analysis`, and not `cluster-computing` (edited).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a dict where each cluster has it's own color. Then I would just add all cluster-colors together multiplyed by their probability:

```
colors = []
cluster_colors = {0:np.array([255,0,0]),1:np.array([0,255,0]),2:np.array([0,0,255])}
for n in range(X.shape[0]):
    color = np.zeros([3])
    for c in range(P.shape[0]):
        color += cluster_colors[c]*P[c,n]

    colors.append(color)
```

When I understood your data right, this should just work.

Comment: @Phinie I'm sure you could still optimize it using pandas or numpy to make this more efficient for lots of data but for me, any visualisation has just so little data that for loops are totally fine and don't take to long

Answer (score 0):

You can use [plotly](https://plotly.com/) which is a good charting library outthere for this purposes.An example will be like below where you can set size and colour for each category.

```
#import plotly library 
import plotly.express as px
#get the iris datset 
df = px.data.iris()
#plot the scatter plot by setting size and colour 
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species",
                 size='petal_length', hover_data=['petal_width'])
fig.show()
```